# T-SQL Lead () function issue while using GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert, window-functions

I am trying to insert data from several tables into the one resulting table.

But, since I am using the `Lead()` function in `SELECT` / `GROUP BY` - for creating one of the fields, I am having an error:

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clause

How should I modify my code so it would work?

```
      USE [WH];
      INSERT INTO [exp].[Profile] (

                   [MedicalConditionFK]
                 , [EHRProgramFK]
                 , [EffectiveDate]
                 , [ExpirationDate]

               )

       SELECT 
              c.medicalcondition_id
            , Max(ISNULL(epi.[EHRProgramFK], -1)) AS [EHRProgramFK]
            , p.[effective_date] AS [EffectiveDate]
            , DateAdd(day, -1, lead (p.[effective_date], 1, '2050-12-31') OVER 
                      (partition by p.[client_id], c.[medicalcondition_id] Order By 
                                                   p.[effective_date])) AS [ExpirationDate] 

      FROM 
            [exp].[Condition] c
            INNER JOIN [exp].[Medical] p ON 
                                         c.[ClientMedicalProfile_id] = p.[ClientMedicalProfile_id]
            LEFT JOIN [exp].[Episode] epi ON 
                                         (p.[effective_date] BETWEEN epi.[AdmissionDate] 
                                          AND epi.[DischargeDate] and epi.[DBCode] = 'CS-SM')

      WHERE
            (p.[effective_date] IS NOT NULL)


      GROUP BY
              c.medicalcondition_id
            , p.[effective_date]
            , DateAdd(day, -1, lead (p.[effective_date], 1, '2050-12-31') OVER 
                  (partition by p.[client_id], c.[medicalcondition_id] Order By p.[effective_date]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your query valid, you need to put the columns that are used in the window function in the `group by` clause (not the window function itself).

Basically it means that you have to add column `client_id`:

```
GROUP BY
    c.medicalcondition_id,
    p.[effective_date],
    p.[client_id]
```

While this will avoid the syntax error, I cannot tell if this will produce the resultset that you want. For this, you would probably need to ask a new question, providing proper sample data and desired results.